# Restrição de Acesso,em Projeto do Visual Studio,com C#!

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Durante o meu curso técnico de informática,no módulo de Programação,fiz um projeto com Windows Form!
Esse projeto está ligado a um banco de dados criado por mim mesma no SQL Server!

Seria um "software" para clinica médica(tudo ficticio), de inicio tenho uma tela onde quem acessa ira colocar: Usuario,Senha e Setor de Atuação!
Existem apenas três setores que podem acessar o sistema: Médicos,Administrador e Recepcionista! Sendo que cada um vai ter acesso diferente,ou seja o Adm é quem pode acessar todo o sistema,ja médicos e recepcionista terão acesso negado a algumas áreas!

Eu fiz um DAL e também fiz os códigos do botão que ira permitir o acesso ao sistema!
Só que ele me da uma mesagem de erro:
[image: Errooo]

O Problema é que não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro!
Seguem abaixo imagem do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Infelismente terei que colocar o código mesmo,pois não consigo tirar print do código inteiro,sem cortar ele!

**

```
}
            dr.Close();
            return seto.SetorRestricao;
           }
               public string logasenha(string usuarioRestricao,string senhaRestricao,string setoAtu)
               {
                  SqlConnection NanoTec = new SqlConnection(Conexao.ObtemConexao());
                  NanoTec.Open();
                  SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("select * from Restricao where NomeUsuario = '" + usuarioRestricao + "' , SenhadeAcesso = '" + senhaRestricao + "' AND SetorAtuacao = '" + setoAtu + "'" , NanoTec);
                  SqlDataReader dr = Comando.ExecuteReader();
                   RestricaoDAL senha = new RestricaoDAL();
                     while (dr.Read())
                     {
                        senha.SenhaRestricao = dr["SenhaRestricao"].ToString();
                        }
                            return senha.SenhaRestricao;
            }
    }
}
```

**

Alguém para ajudar? Depois dessa ajuda precisarei de outra,mas não irei postar ela até achar o meu erro claro!

Obrigada Carol!

Comment: Troca a virgula dentro da consulta por um AND

Comment: Assim: SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("select * from Restricao where NomeUsuario = '" + usuarioRestricao + "' AND SenhadeAcesso = '" + senhaRestricao + "' AND SetorAtuacao = '" + setoAtu + "'" , NanoTec);

Comment: Denis Rudnei,muito obrigada pela ajuda! Arrumei o código e deu certinho!

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/55024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é um erro de sintaxe do sql.

Altere a linha;

```
SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("select * from Restricao where NomeUsuario = '" + usuarioRestricao + "' , SenhadeAcesso = '" + senhaRestricao + "' AND SetorAtuacao = '" + setoAtu + "'" , NanoTec);
```

Para;

```
SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("select * from Restricao where NomeUsuario = '" + usuarioRestricao + "' and SenhadeAcesso = '" + senhaRestricao + "' AND SetorAtuacao = '" + setoAtu + "'" , NanoTec);
```